# get currency symbol using php

Tags: php, character-encoding, locale, currency

I am using the following code as an example

```
$locale = 'cy_GB';
setlocale ( LC_MONETARY  , $locale );
$conv = localeconv();           
$currencyRateSymbol = $conv['int_curr_symbol'];
var_dump($currencyRateSymbol);
```

The problem is that I am getting `string '�' (length=1)` when I am looking for `£`

This is happening for every locale that I use including baht, pound and euro.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Who says that '�' is a wrong character? You might only display it wrong here. Please also add `bin2hex($currencyRateSymbol)`, `'£'` and `bin2hex('£')` to your `var_dump` and update your question.

Comment: it is wrong because it was working as I expected before and for some reason its not now

Comment: Please check my updated comment and add the needed information to your question. In it's current form your question is ambiguous and the description of your problem fuzzy. That is why you see a downvote probably.

Comment: I have a code example and expected output. How is it possibly fuzzy? anyway @deceze answered it correctly

Comment: It is fuzzy because we do not see the binary information of both the actual and the expected character. @Deceze *assumed* that this would solve your issue. Take care that locales are system-dependent. If the suggested locales would not exist, this would not have solved your issue for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`length=1` means it's one byte long. "�" means you're trying to display it as Unicode and the Unicode decoder could not decode this byte correctly. The £ symbol encoded in UTF-8 is two bytes.

Ergo...

The £ symbol is not encoded in UTF-8, but you are trying to decode it as UTF-8, hence it fails.

Use the UTF-8 version of your locale if it exists on your system (e.g. `cy_GB.UTF-8`) or specify the correct encoding to the client that's trying to display this (probably ISO-8859-1).

Comment: Might be the answer. I wonder about *bhat*, I don't know it well. Also is there a way to find out the character encoding used after setting the locale (`setlocale ( LC_MONETARY  , $locale );`)?

Comment: adding `.UTF-8` to `$locale` fixed it.

Comment: @hakre I'm not sure about that, my knowledge on locales is spotty.