# Verification of currency symbols in webpage using selenium webdriver

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, currency

For ecommerce web applications, I need to verify whether the correct currency symbol is displayed or not, depending on the country.

In the below site,

http://www.moltonbrown.co.uk/store/index.jsp

am checking for the currency symbol in the basket summary.

In Selenium IDE, when I do verifyText for xpath //div/span[contains(text(),'£18.00')], it runs well.  But, when I use the same xpath in selenium webdriver automation code and try to verify the element, it displays:

```
//div/span[contains(text(),'�18.00')]
Element not found
false
***************
//div/span[contains(text(),'�18.00')]
*************
***************not present***************
```

I saw this [get currency symbol using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198197/get-currency-symbol-using-php) . But couldnt understand what should be done to overcome this.

Thanks in advance,
Suchitra

Comment: @Fraser asks "How do you get selenium IDE to verify a currency symbol (£) on the page in the first place?"

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your currency symbol is turned into a `�` indicates there is a character set issue that is causing your problem.    From the web-driver documentation, there is "limited" support of unicode by using UTF-8.  Limited probably means "buggy".

In any case, you should verify that that the file that runs this test is saved using UTF-8, and that the bytes for your currency symbol are correct for UTF-8.   If this file is in some other character set, save it as UTF-8 and try again.

Here is somebody that had a similar problem with the `ä` character and python drivers.  [Sending unicode with Selenium Webdriver on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255489/sending-unicode-with-selenium-webdriver-on-python)  They were able to solve the problem by changing the declared character set of their python file.